# How to apply validation for Dynamically added fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Iam using javascript validation methods and rules for my form.And it is working fine.But I have an option that user can add many phonenumbers using clicking on a button `Add More`.But how to validate those fields through javascript.Bec we did'nt know how many fields user can add...I have tried with

```
jQuery.validator.addClassRules({
    'phneClass' : {
         required:true,
         numeric : true
     },
     'name' : {
         required : true
     } 
});
```

I need to give 2 diff messages for the both required fields.How can I achieve that.Thanks in advance.

Comment: use [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: @DarkBee.Thanku .But how can I give validation messages..??

Answer (score 0):

- You are using this validator: http://jqueryvalidation.org/?
- Has your input fields the class 'phneClass'?

Maybe your have to call the addClassRules method after you added a new phonenumber field

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In that you can add html5 required attr to the generated input field inside the form that makes validation

check this link also

http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/

http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/09-required.html